# sync office 365 Outlook Calendar with office 365 SharePoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, office-365, office-integration

I want to synchronize office 365 outlook calendar with office 365 SharePoint calendar. How to do this ? Is it Possible ?

Comment: did you get an answer to this? I too want to do the same thing.

Comment: We just looked into this for a customer, what my colleague said was it is not possible yet, but it is a planned enhancement. However, that was before I saw all of that stuff about MS planning to deprecate the ability to sync SharePoint tasks with Outlook client.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible ootb, but you can get a better view if you synchronize the SharePoint calendar to the client software Outlook 2013. That way you are able to see both calendars side by side.