# Office 365 mailbox event sync with SharePoint event list calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

I want Office 365 mail box event in my SharePoint list

I'm referring this [Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62703/sync-office-365-outlook-calendar-with-office-365-sharepoint-calendar) but guy said it's not possible,but SharePoint and Office 365 is connected with each other so I think it may be possible,
If you have any suggestion I would be really appreciate

**Tried Solution:**

I tried to overlay from Exchange

[image: Overlay calendar]

In them I give it two links as follow

**Outlook Web Access URL:** https://outlook.office365.com/owa/

**Exchange Web Service URL:** https://outlook.myexchange.com

but It gives **error** "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'outlook.myexchange.com'. (e82daf9d-20d7-3000-bf7a-e3ebb1a7f673)"

It display look like

[image: SSL error in calendar overlay]

but how can I overcome this certificate  error in office 365?
OR suggest any other way to short out

Comment: Can you check the url in different browser ? IE / crome / firefox

Comment: It happens with each browser,I try to go directly on this link "https://outlook.office.com/owa/" from browser it gives certification error@MonicaJagani

Comment: Can you add that site as trusted site in IE. Then the certification error should go.

Comment: Add in trusted site but not working :(,btw thanks for frequent reply

Comment: Can u check this http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/overlay-user-calendars-on-sharepoint/60bb61d5-5e3b-4222-87e5-74bfa455cb7b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SharePoint Online Doesn't support Calendar overlay with Exchange web service**

[here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a) microsoft mention on which version of sharepoint applies overlay In that list "SharePoint Online" is not there

and I have talked with microsoft person to raising the issue in Office 365,Hw also talled me the same

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of license purchased. If you purchase one of the "P" plans (targeted at the SMB space, scoped to less than 50 total users), there is no SSL available for SharePoint Online sites. If you purchase an "E" SKU for enterprises, SharePoint Online sites are SSL encrypted. As far as I know, all Exchange Online and Lync Online traffic is encrypted for all licenses.

Pingback from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/ed888f06-7a95-4155-bee1-36ecb13dcb66/does-office-365-support-ssl?forum=onlineservicesexchange

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because SharePoint have their own certificate store that misses the certificate chain for the Exchange server.

Follow this article to add the trust 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2011/05/31/sharepoint-and-exchange-calendar-together/

Comment: I follow mention URL but,my site is in office 365 , so how can we create certificate or any IIS access ..?@Monica